# Recommended way in overloading methods with same signature

Tags: groovy, overloading

I want to call `send` method in different ways:

```
send( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' )
send( 'a', 'c', 'd' )
send( 'b', 'c', 'd' )
send( 'c', 'd' )
```

I have:

`void send ( String aStr = null, String bStr = null, String cStr, String dStr )`.

I know that the intention of calling `send( 'b', 'c', 'd' )` will use the overloaded signature `send( String aStr, String cStr, String dStr )` and not the `send( String bStr, String cStr, String dStr )` signature

What is the ideal way to solve this? Is there a better way than using a Map or custom Object reference type to get `send( 'b', 'c', 'd' )`?

Comment: Default value for beginning parameters, seems strange, did this work like You want? Using Map is orthodox  in Groovy for variable number of parameters, especially parameters name are known for method algorithm.

Comment: I have lost important idea during commenting, correction: Map is a way to give NAMED parameters. These are accessed in different way internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading relies on the fact that two methods with the same name may be distinguished by the number and type of the arguments.

In your case however you have at least two situations where the number of arguments is the same (3) and the type of the arguments is the same (e.g. String).

The question is: How to indicate whether you want the behavior of `send('a','c','d')` or of `send('b','c','d')`?

I suggest you invoke your method by passing an object and defining your variables within the method.

```
def send(obj){
    def a = obj.a
    def b = obj.b
    def c = obj.c
    def d = obj.d

    println a //a
    println b //b
    println c //null
    println d //d
}

myMethod([a:'a',b:'b',d:'d']);
```

In this way the object you send is a `LinkedHashMap`. If you try to retrieve a value that is not in the map (e.g. `obj.c`) you will get `null`, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: +1 Overloading relies on the fact that two methods with the same name may be distinguished by the number and type of the arguments.